# How to fetch last inserted record from dynamoDB using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

How to fetch last inserted record from dynamoDB using boto3?

Comment: Look at DynamoDB Streams https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

Answer (score 2):

Before doing the following, be sure to run `$ aws configure` and insert your credentials:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Your_Table')

response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('entry').eq('latest_entry_identifier'))
items = response['Items']
print(items)
```

Comment: Can this be configured through Dynamodb UI by enabling stream option (any one of four)  ... in my case timestamp is primary key

Comment: Can you please describe in detailed steps to enable Dynamodb streams and  which options to enable to get latest_entry_ identifier ?